# Restoring Exchange 2007 MailBox DB to a New Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange-2007

Test Machine, Installed Server 2008 X64, installed the backup software I used to backup exchange, catalog the media, extracted the Mailbox database, catalogs, logs into the appropriate locations ( D:\Database and E:\Logs) exactly the same logical partition layout as the original server. (This server is completely separate from the production domain / LAN).

a) Have named this test machine as the original server
b) Dcpromo - Installed AD with the same domain name as the production domain

c) Shall I just install Exchange 2007 SP1 now and :

i   - Name the Exchange Organization as the original server
ii  - Create a New Database (First storage group\mailbox databse) (Do Not mount it)
iii - "Allow File restore true" (DB properties)
iv  - Copy the database files (.edb files, log files, and Exchange Search catalog) to the appropriate location.

**Q : Is it just the matter of copying and pasting the db's in there original location or can I mount them from a new location too ?
Q : DB is in clean shutdown state, would I need log / catalogs ?**

**Q** : How would I get the Active Directory back on this test box ? Can i RESTORE just the active directory onto this new machine ? as When I tried to restore the whole operating system from within windows, it restored fine and when it rebooted, I logged in as the original administrator and it will give me activation error - i have forgotten the exact wording but it was like "windows have discovered some activation problem"

Will look forward to your helpful suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never tried just copying files.  Typically you dismount the mailbox and make sure the the checkbox for this database can be overwritten by a restore, then restore the database.  Before even installing exchange I would restore AD from backups.  You should be able to do a complete bare metal restore.  you might get an activation error but that shouldn't prevent functionality (worst case it reboots in a few hours- but you should be able to reactivate before then)

Here is the link to the [disaster recovery procedures](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998890(EXCHG.80).aspx) in technet.  The basic exchange 2007 page has [additional disaster recovery documentation and webcasts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/bb288461.aspx#recovery)